# How to fetch data from different blogs into a single web Portal?

Tags: php, blogs, feed

I am Working in PHP MySql project, I Have A Page Called Live Information, And Client need this page to function like all the information from different blogs related to some specific topic must be displayed on this page.

So Any Direction On how can it be done?

Comment: Will It Provide Me all the Updated post's detail along with videos and Pics?

Comment: certainly, no. As blogger you can define what data do you want to feed to your RSS. I might choose to not present ALL of the corresponding data to my post (like photos, images, number of comments or whatsoever...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the blogs give out an RSS feed you can use an RSS library like [Magpie](http://magpierss.sourceforge.net/) to get at the data.

If they don't, you'll need to get their HTML and parse. You'll most probably have to write a parser for each site. Have a look at [web scraping](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=web%20scraping).